# PHP Download script error failed to load PDF document

Tags: php, download

I have a simple download script that can be found below:

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])){

        $name = $_GET['name'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT link_to_policy FROM policies WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $result2 = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $policytodownload = $result2["link_to_policy"];
        if (file_exists($policytodownload)) {
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            header("Content-Type: application/msword");
            header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($policytodownload));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($policytodownload);
            exit;
        }   
    }
```

link_to_policy column contains the full path to the file where the policy has been saved. After clicking on the link, the file is downloaded, but after clicking on the file, even if it is a word document, I receive an error message in Chrome (all the PDF files are meant to be opened there): Failed to load PDF document.

Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't send multiple `Content-type` headers.

Comment: Why not? I mean there are 3 possible file extensions so that is why I want to. How I could do that then? Thank you!

Comment: You're only sending one file, you need to send the actual type of that file.

Comment: Check the extension and send the appropriate content type for that extension.

Comment: Yes, I know that I am sending one file, however, this is the download script for all of the policies not just for one particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't send multiple `Content-type` headers, send the appropriate type for the file extension.

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])){

    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT link_to_policy FROM policies WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $result2 = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $policytodownload = $result2["link_to_policy"];
    if (file_exists($policytodownload)) {
        $type_map = ['xls' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                     'doc' => 'application/msword',
                     'pdf' => 'application/pdf'];
        $ext = pathinfo($policytodownload, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (isset($type_map[$ext])) {
            header("Content-Type: {$type_map[$ext]}");
        }
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($policytodownload));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($policytodownload);
        exit;
    }   
}
```